# How can I determine the Reason IE is going into Compatibility View Mode and prevent it from happening?

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Okay, here are the facts regarding our problem:

- The web site we are working on is designed to use modern HTML5 features. This includes indexedDb.
- We are using the following HTML right at the top of each page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
```

- All our users are using the same version of IE11.
- We have 200+ active users who use the site, and for most of them, everything works just fine. The browser stays in "Edge" mode.
- So far though, 3 of those users' browsers started opening the pages on the site in Compatibility View Mode *instead* of the default Edge mode. It *was* working for them fine previously.
- If any other user goes to any page that those 3 users went to, they open fine (in Edge mode).
- I created a super-simple diagnostic page devoid of CSS, HTML5 features, etc., when the users who are having the problems go to this page, it STILL going into compatibility view mode!  It seems once the damage has been done, the browser wants to go into compatibility view mode for that domain regardless of the page content!
- We've tried deleting Browsing History in the user's browser including cookies and website data... it does not fix the problem.
- Restarting the PC does not work.
- We do not have enough security to access any registry settings or directories where the browser stores its files.

So for starters, the question is, what steps can we take to figure out WHY their browsers when into compatibility mode in the first place. The only things I'm finding are vague error messages in the F12 console about using some feature or other improperly. No info about what feature or what error it caused.

And then, if that can be resolved, for users already in this mess, is there any viable steps we can take to get them so they see the site in Edge mode once again.

I'll be grateful for any help I can get on this.  I am really stumped on this one!

Comment: Is it going into compatibility mode or launching IE11 instead of Edge? On the Win 10 machines I support, these are two separate programs.

Comment: this is not the Edge browser we're talking about. It's IE11. The default "mode" that it is in (unless switched to Compatibility View Mode) is called "Edge" -- the reasoning behind this... I do not know :P

All our users are running Windows 7 Professional